# How do I use the twilio-php library to retrieve all calls made between two dates?

Tags: php, sms, twilio

Using the following code I am able to get the logs of calls and SMS's. How do I modify this code to only search between certain dates using PHP?

```
// Instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client 
$client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken, $ApiVersion); 

// http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart... 
try { 
  // Get Recent Calls 
  foreach ($client->account->calls as $call) { 
    echo "Call from $call->sid : $call->from to $call->to at $call->start_time of length $call->duration $call->price <br>"; 
  } 
} 
catch (Exception $e) { 
  echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to add a code snippet that looks something like this:

```
$client = new Services_Twilio('AC123', '123');
foreach ($client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 50, array(
    'StartTime>' => '2012-04-01',
    'StartTime<' => '2012-05-01'
)) as $call) {
    echo "From: {$call->from}\nTo: {$call->to}\nSid: {$call->sid}\n\n";
}
```

If you want to filter the list, you have to construct the iterator yourself with the `getIterator` command. There's more documentation here: [Filtering Twilio Calls with PHP](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/calls.html#filtering-calls)

Answer (score 1):

User search terms `StartTime>` and `StartTime<` for this. First one means call start time is greater than and last one means call start time is less than.

To find every calls that started between 4th and 6th July of 2009 add search term

```
array(
    'StartTime>' => '2009-07-04',
    'StartTime<' => '2009-07-06'
)
```

See example 4 on the [twilio doc](http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call).

Also note you can always ask twilio support. They usually help gladly.

Comment: Where do you put the code in my example? You are missing some code to demonstrate where to put the array... I'll go check your link and try and figure it out...

Comment: You can talk to twilio support about this. They provide tech support.